Foreign Key dropdown in Admin returns __str__, can I change it so some other column?
Here is my setup:
# myapp.models
class Country(models.Model):
  alpha2 = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=2),
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64,

  def __str__(self):
    return "%(alpha2)s %(name)s" % {"alpha2": self.alpha2, "name", self.name}

class Address(models.Model):
  id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
  province = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

# myapp.admin
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Address, Country

admin.site.register(Address)
admin.site.register(Country)

When I go to http://localhost:8000/admin, and go to add a new Address, the country dropdown shows the output of Country().__str__ (i.e. IN India). I have 2 questions:

I believe I would be able to choose what I want to show in the dropdown if I was writing my own form (without changing __str__). Is this correct?
Can I change what I want to show in admin panel without changing __str__?

